# Style an item in a list based on its property in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am very new to Vuejs, so please pardon me if this is something very common. But I am trying to style an item based on the condition of whether the name of the item is equal to another object.

```
<template>
  <div id="subMenuWrapper">
    <ul id="subMenuList">
      <li v-for="menu in SubMenuItems" v-bind:class="{activeSubMenuItem === menu.name? activeSubMenuItemStyle:subMenuItemStyle}">{{menu.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'subMenuWrapper',
  data() {
    return {
      SubMenuItems: [
        {
          name: 'IN THEATERS',
        },
        {
          name: 'COMING SOON',
        },
      ],
      activeSubMenuItem: 'IN THEATERS',
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.activeSubMenuItemStyle {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e4bb23;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.subMenuItemStyle {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e4bb23;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
</style>
```

This is giving me an error:

> Vue template syntax error:
>
> - invalid expression: v-bind:class="{activeSubMenuItem === menu.name? activeSubMenuItemStyle:subMenuItemStyle}"

How can I style an item in a list based on its properties?

**Update:**

Tried this way too:

```
<li v-for="menu in SubMenuItems" v-bind:class="[activeSubMenuItem === menu.name? activeSubMenuItemStyle:subMenuItemStyle]">{{menu.name}}</li>
```

and added the `activeSubMenuItemStyle` and `subMenuItemStyle` into the *data* with style properties.

This is not giving any errors, but the item has no styles

Comment: You have no style because your CSS is not being read, it can be something related to your build process. Remove the CSS from the template file and make it global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you are using a ternary expression, you need to use different brackets:

`<div v-bind:class="[isActive ? activeClass : '', errorClass]">`

Should work after this correction.

Try to refer to docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax . If it won't work - let me know, I'll try to edit answer to help.

2. As pet Mat comment, `<li v-for="menu in SubMenuItems" v-bind:class="[activeSubMenuItem === menu.name? 'activeSubMenuItemStyle':'subMenuItemStyle']">{{menu.name}}</li>`

Comment: Yes, I tried that way too `<li v-for="menu in SubMenuItems" v-bind:class="[activeSubMenuItem === menu.name? activeSubMenuItemStyle:subMenuItemStyle]">{{menu.name}}</li>`. Its not giving any errors, but its not having any styles.

Comment: `activeSubMenuItemStyle`, if this is the name of the css class, you should put that in quotes like a string. Anything inside the quotes of `v-bind:class` should be a valid javascript expression, in your case, they might be interpreted as undeclared variables. try `v-bind:class="[activeSubMenuItem === menu.name? 'activeSubMenuItemStyle':'subMenuItemStyle']"`

Comment: Kakar - please put jsfiddle together with your code to let us help you