# how to use data object into a style tag? vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So i am trying to create a parallax effect by targeting background-position with a data object.

```
<div class="parallaxBanner" :style="{scrollBanner}">
</div>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function(){
            return{
                scrollBanner: 0,
            }
        },
        methods:{
            scrollPosition: function(){
                this.scrollbanner = window.scrollY % 0.5;
                console.log(window.scrollY);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
          window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollPosition);
        }
    }
</script>
```

not 100% how to target css in line value any suggestions would be a big help :)

Comment: you can also assign any computed method directly which will return an object of style attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style an item in a list based on its property in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339312/style-an-item-in-a-list-based-on-its-property-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `background-position`, you can use

```
<div class="parallaxBanner" :style="{ backgroundPosition: scrollBanner }">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign method in style and write one method in computed:

HTML

```
<Row>
  <i-col :span="5" :style="styles" class="sidebar">
    <f-sidebar></f-sidebar>
  </i-col>
</Row>
```

SCRIPT

```
computed: {
  styles () {
    return {
      style.position = 'fixed'
      style['z-index'] = '99'
      style.height = '100%'
      style.background = '#363e4f'
    }
  }
}
```